# Changing colour of active bootstrap nav-link using styled component in Nextjs app.(typescript)

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, next.js, styled-components

I am using react-bootstrap and styled components in my react typescript app. I want change the colour of active nav-link.

code:

```
const StyledNav = styled(Nav)`
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
`;
```

```
  <StyledNav>
     <StyledNav.Link>BACK </StyledNav.Link>
     <StyledNav.Link>HOME </StyledNav.Link>
     <StyledNav.Link active>{props.page}</StyledNav.Link>
  </StyledNav>
```

TIA

Comment: Hi @heisenberg, it may be a question for a post, but i just saw that you used Bootstrap with Next.js and Typescript. Can I ask you how did you install Bootstrap on the app, or how can I do it nowadays? I've been looking around but I haven't seen anything about it. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use props in your template literals.

```
const StyledLink = styled(Nav.Link)`
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: ${props => props.active ? 'red': 'inherit'};
`;
```

If you want to have multiple definitions you can use it like;

```
const StyledLink = styled(Nav.Link)`
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  ${props => props.active && `
    color: red;
    border-bottom: 3px solid green;
  `}
`;

  <Nav>
     <StyledLink>BACK </StyledLink>
     <StyledLink>HOME </StyledLink>
     <StyledLink active>{props.page}</StyledLink>
  </Nav>
```

Comment: it seems to not working. That styling is for the div which consists of the 3link. so styling changes for that div does not have any effect fo the ones inside it.

Comment: @heisenberg please create StyledLink and use it instead of using StyledNav.Link

Comment: still the color seems no to change because, [.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link] class is having more priority than the "StyledLink". prop tag and all is working now, color is getting overridden

Comment: @heisenberg If you are using styled.component why do you have class definitions for your elements?

Comment: adding a "!important" solves the problem, but i think that is not the right way to do?

Comment: @heisenberg Yes it will solve it but you need reconsider your application structure. It is not smart to use both classNames and styled.components.

Comment: FYI ihavent used classnmae anywhere. it is the default bootstrap class.